# scrollPane can't get scrollbar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a scrollPane that I am filling dynamically in my code. The problem is that I can't get it to grow in scope.

I've tried a lot of the tips I can find online but nothing gets it to appear.

I'm looping out 10 components but the size always stays the same.

```
  B = new JScrollPane();
     B.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       B.setViewportBorder(null);

          B.setBounds(12, 53, 330, 400);

       //making the scrollPane

       loadArtists(country); 


       // loading the method with the content


    contentPane.add(B);

       // the content method

               public void loadArtists(String country){
    ArrayList<Artist> top10A = Methods.getTopArtist(country); // top atrister

    B.removeAll();

    String [] genre =Methods.getGenreArtist(country);                                           
    Component2[] comp = new Component2[10]; // skriv ut infohållare

    for (int i = 0; i < top10A.size(); i++) {
        comp[i] = new Component2(this);
        comp[i].setBounds(0, 0, 327, 68);
        comp[i].setLocation(0, 0 + space2);
        ImageIcon[] panel= new ImageIcon[10];

        int lyssnare = top10A.get(0).getListeners();

        try {
                URL url2 = new             URL((top10A.get(i).getImageURL(ImageSize.valueOf("MEDIUM"))));  
                panel[i]= new ImageIcon(url2);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                panel[i]= new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/bilder/super.jpg"));
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        comp[i].setInfo(panel[i],top10A.get(i).getListeners(), top10A.get(i).getName().toString(), String.valueOf(i+1),genre[i],lyssnare,"");

        B.add(comp[i]);
        space2 = space2 + 75;

               //B.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

         B.repaint();
    }
}
```

Ok so this is were I'm at. I will get the scroll but it only let me scroll 1mm. And if I remove the setBounds the whole scrollpane goes away. I don't know how to work around it. Sorry if I'm a bit daft but this is my first "real program":

```
   scroll1 = new JScrollPane();
     scroll1.setViewportBorder(null);

         scroll1.setBounds(12, 53, 330, 400);

          setComponents = new JPanel();

 contentPane.add(scroll1);


 scroll1.setViewportView(setComponents);
 GroupLayout gl_testP = new GroupLayout(setComponents);
 gl_testP.setHorizontalGroup(
    gl_testP.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 307, Short.MAX_VALUE)
 );
 gl_testP.setVerticalGroup(
    gl_testP.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 398, Short.MAX_VALUE)
 );
 setComponents.setLayout(gl_testP);

 loadArtists(country);     




 public void loadArtists(String country){
    ArrayList<Artist> top10A = Methods.getTopArtist(country); // top atrister

    setComponents.removeAll();

    String [] genre =Methods.getGenreArtist(country);                                           
    Component2[] comp = new Component2[10]; // skriv ut infohållare

    for (int i = 0; i < top10A.size(); i++) {
        comp[i] = new Component2(this);
        comp[i].setBounds(0, 0, 327, 68);
        comp[i].setLocation(0, 0 + space2);
        ImageIcon[] panel= new ImageIcon[10];

        int lyssnare = top10A.get(0).getListeners();

        try {
                URL url2 = new URL((top10A.get(i).getImageURL(ImageSize.valueOf("MEDIUM")))); // skapa array av artist bilder
                panel[i]= new ImageIcon(url2);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                panel[i]= new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/bilder/super.jpg"));
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(panel[i]+" "+"saknar bild");
            }

        comp[i].setInfo(panel[i],top10A.get(i).getListeners(), top10A.get(i).getName().toString(), String.valueOf(i+1),genre[i],lyssnare,"");


        setComponents.add(comp[i]);
        space2 = space2 + 75;
         scroll1.setViewportView(setComponents);

         //B.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

         setComponents.repaint();
    }
}
```

OK. So I "fixed" it.

```
          setComponents.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,750));
```

It's not optimal since it wont let me grow the content dynamically.
But that doesn't really mater right now when I don't need more then 10 components looped.

Answer (score 4):

```
B.setBounds(12, 53, 330, 400);
```

Don't use the setBounds() methods on your components.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The scrollbars will appear automatically when the preferred size of the components added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scroll pane. Layout managers do these calculations for you.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I dont know how to initiate the scrollpane without setbound. if a remove it it goes away. wierd thing with the setbounds is that if a have height at 400 and play the is no scroll. but if i lower it to anything below 400 i will be able to scroll down to 400. somewhere i got way of track trying to solve this minor thing..

Comment: `if a remove it it goes away`. Don't use a null layout!!! The layout manager will set the size of all the components.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the great advice given by Rob Camick, you're also removing all components directly from and trying to add components directly to the JScrollPane ignoring that the JViewport should not be messed with and that visualized components need to be added to the JScrollPane's viewport, not to the JScrollPane itself.

So you could add the component to the JScrollPane's viewport by passing it into the JScrollPane's constructor or you could instead call the JScrollPane's `setViewportView(...)` method if you want to swap views that it holds.

As an aside, please try to use better variable names, names that comply with Java naming standards (for instance variable names should start with a lower-case letter), and names that make sense that make your code self-commenting. The variable name, B, doesn't comply with either of these recommendations.

Also your entire program is lacking use of decent layout managers. You appear to desire to add multiple components to the JScrollPane. Consider creating a JPanel that is held by the JScrollPane's viewport, giving it an appropriate layout, possibly GridLayout(....) and adding the multiple components to this JPanel.

For more specific and informative help, consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: +1, for proper usage of the scrollpane/viewport and Java variable names. I stopped reading after noticing the setBounds(..) issue.

Comment: @camickr: thanks. and 1+ (given 3 hrs ago) for your great recommendations.

Comment: thanx for the input. Im still new to programming and as i get frustrated more of it gets in the the variables. i will do better.     I will try to implement the changes recommended today and get back.